# Since updating to today's version of Skype on Win8, Skype won't even log in

Tags: windows-8, skype

I am using the desktop (win32 not appstore) Skype on Windows 8.  I accepted an auto-update today which now will not let me log into skype at all.

I wiped out the `AppData\Roaming\Skype` folder because that's how you get Skype back in the past when it has gone stupid, but that didn't help either.

I do not get any error message, just the circular progress indicator that lasts forever. (Okay, so far it's been 30 minutes. It may eventually time out yet.)

Other ideas please?  I tried the Windows 8 App Store Skype app (WinRT), which I hate, I guess I'll go back and install that for now.

**Update** Skype 6.0.126 seems to be completely broken on my Win8 machine.

Comment: What error message do you recieve exactly?

Comment: No error. Sorry. Updating.

Comment: Trying using the `Refreshing` your Windows 8 installation.

Comment: That's pretty severe. Last time I did that I lost a lot of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by Skype 6.0.0.126, December 10th.  (5 days of instability)

That's a lot of crappiness recently introduced into Skype. Nice work microsoft.

Oh, and with huge banner ads all over, and the new installer defaulting to changing my home page and my search engine in my web browser.

Microsoft Skype, it's the new "RealPlayer", and is creeping steadily towards Malware status in my book, by becoming a browser homepage and search engine hijacker, by default.

Comment: Then use Google+ hangout